# MYSQL: Sorting results based on average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| id    | coursecodeid   | grade | workload  | easiness    |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     |  10            |  A+   |    5      |   4         |
| 2     |  10            |  A+   |    2      |   4         |
| 3     |  10            |  B    |    3      |   3         |
| 4     |  11            |  B+   |    2      |   3         |
| 5     |  11            |  A+   |    5      |   4         |
| 6     |  12            |  B    |    3      |   3         |
| 7     |  11            |  B+   |    7      |   8         |
| 8     |  11            |  A+   |    1      |   2         |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to sort the results (`coursecodeid`) based on average calculated of each course.

The average would be like this

```
all workload values of the grade against courseid
+ all easiness values of the grade against courseid
/ 2
```

From this example `coursecodeid = '10'` has three entries

```
avgworkload(5+ 2 + 3)/3=x 
avgeasiness(4 + 4 + 3)/3 = y
answer x+y/2 = z
```

So we had to calculate the averages of each course like this and shows the `coursecodeids` based on the averages we get

and grade should be shown based on maximum occurrence of particular course.

I am running this query but it isn't working as expected

```
SELECT 
 coursecode.id,
 feedback.grade CourseGrade,

 (( AVG( workload ) + AVG( easiness )) /2 ) as Avg
FROM coursecode
LEFT JOIN feedback ON feedback.coursecodeID = coursecode.id
GROUP BY coursecode.id
ORDER BY Avg DESC
LIMIT 11
```

Comment: So what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Strawberry please check my updated question

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Hang on. No one said anything about feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    (AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness)) / 2 AS result
FROM
    metagen.new_table
GROUP BY coursecodeid;
```